# Play Multiple Video Items Simultaneously/Synchronously in iOS

Tags: video, ios5, avfoundation

Does anybody have any good ideas for hacks to get multiple videos playing simultaneously in iOS5? It seems AVFoundation for iOS still doesn't support playback of multiple items simultaneously yet.

I actually want to play an embedded video in one part of my screen, and then have another part alternate between playing the same video, in synchrony with the first one, and not showing anything at all. The user would toggle whether the second view would be parroting the first video in real time.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 instances of `AVPlayer` playing the same video (with 2 different instances of `AVPlayerItem`) at the same time.

I haven't researched the *synchronously* part, but you can play/pause/seek at the same time easily looking perfectly synchronous to the human eye.